# In my scheduleAtFixedRate method, I put delay time to start run the method. But this delay time cannot work and run immediatly

Tags: java, scheduler

Here my code,

```
static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = null;
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Testing(),60, 24*60*60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);


public static Runnable Testing()
{ System.out.println("Testing...");
}
```

I want to call Runnable() method after 60 seconds later, but it call this method immediatly when i run the code.
Is there any problem in my code.
I'm new for scheduleAtFixedRate method.
Thanks :)

Comment: What is Runnable? static class or method

Comment: Sry, I edited again.

Comment: Not returning Runnable type from the testing()

Comment: Other than the syntax error, the code for scheduleAtFixedRate method works correctly. Try running the code in the codiva.io online compiler for java https://www.codiva.io/p/d1bfeb1f-0895-4c72-b5fb-d99cfb05051b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Testing...");
  }
}, 60, 24*60*60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: it work. :) But what is different between my method. Actually this method have only one line, right?

Comment: this is just sample print out msg to ask question.

Comment: In my real program, inside my method, there are so many line. how to write like that?

Comment: @Alice you are not returning Runnable reference in the method. You need to mention you basic code to understand

Comment: Sry, for my incomplete code, this is just for sample to ask question. I want to  call Runnable() method like your answer. I cannot call this method according to delay time. Now, its o k. Thanks

Comment: Here my code,    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new amcRunnable(), 60, 24*60*60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends Runnable.

```
  static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println(i + " : Testing ... Current timestamp: " + new Date());
      // Put any relevant code here.
    }
  }
```

Then your code works as expected. Try running the full working code here at [codiva.io online compiler ide](https://www.codiva.io/p/d1bfeb1f-0895-4c72-b5fb-d99cfb05051b).

A related suggestion, in professional code, people generally avoid using thread scheduler to run a task that runs daily. The most common option is to use cron job and a bit more setup. But that is out side the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for yr answer :).

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: similar, But i already got my answer with the first answer, and also appreciate about your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The Runnable is an interface and you must implement the run() method. You could try to change your code to

```
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Testing...");
        }
    },60, 24*60*60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```